# Android loop bytecode comparison

Tags: android, optimization, loops, bytecode, dalvik

I've been doing some experiments with loops in Android and got puzzled with the results.

In the past I read somewhere that (in C++??) if you translate this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i != Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
{
   // Do something
}
```

...into this loop:

```
for(int i = threshold; --i >= 0; )
{
    // Do the same
}
```

You could get a significant increase of performance since the second variant would generate a comparison with zero which due to processors architectures is much faster than the comparison between two non-zero values on the first loop.

I wanted to see if this held true in Android so I started by writting the code and used DEX to peek at the generated Dalvik's bytecode to check there was not any kind of compiler optimization going around.

Indeed these were the results:

```
0003dc: 1201                                   |000e: const/4 v1, #int 0 // #0  
0003de: 1402 ffff ff7f                         |000f: const v2, #float NaN // #7fffffff 
0003e4: 3321 5000                              |0012: if-ne v1, v2, 0062 // +0050 

000434: 1401 ffff ff7f                         |003a: const v1, #float NaN // #7fffffff
00043a: d801 01ff                              |003d: add-int/lit8 v1, v1, #int -1 // #ff 
00043e: 3b01 2800                              |003f: if-gez v1, 0067 // +0028
```

(It's irrelevant the code at 0062 and 0067 for the matter since I'm just concerned by the loop it self).

Well, but we can see clearly that there is no optimization introduced by the compiler/translator since both loop syntaxes have different generated bytecode.

Now that the context is set and that I proved that it would be useful to proceed the testing it's time for the question:

**"Having I profiled the code above and found out the no matter the order of the loop's execution the first always takes more time than the second, what I am missing here?"**

Is something like JIT-compiling doing some optimization for me?

I would expect that both the loops behaved differently since the generated bytecode is not the same.

Thanks a lot on any effort put to enlighten me on this question.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following thoughts. First of all, dalvik bytecode is not executed directly on processor - it's still bytecode and it should be transformed into native code.

Secondly, lets consider why the second case in C++ (x86 platform) will be faster then the first:

1. So in the first case you will have a code like: `inc (i)`, then to
   compare two values processor will subtract the first value from the
   second and check if the result is equal to 0 (using `jz` instruction or something like this).
2. In the second case processor will `dec (i)` and then the result value will compare with 0 (using jz).

Thus, you can see that the second case is shorter for one instruction. I guess that the same thing occurs in ARM processors, that's why the second loop is faster then the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yury! Question is: the second loop is not faster than the first. If you switch de execution order (ie run the second loop I presented before the first) the later will always be faster. Though your idea that DEX is turned into native code prior to running might explain the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the first assembly the if-ne instruction compares two values (v1 and v2) and jumps based on the result. This is slower than just comparing one value with zero like the if-gez instruction does in the second case. But perhaps I misunderstand your question, do you mean that both loops run in the same execution time? It is not clear from your question. What timings do you get?

Comment: Thanks, Ville! As I stated on Yury's comment the time is independent of the loop's execution order. Now matter which you put first it will always run slower...